# Problemas de Instalacion de Mariadb

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb, debian

buenas trato de instalar un servidor web, pero suceden problemas en la instalacion de mariadb, actualmente estoy usando debian 9 y al tratar de instalar mariadb me aparece[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

busque informacion y me menciona que hay procesos instalados en mmariadb pero con busqueda find no encuentro ninguno para removerlo o purgarlo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi version de debian es [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los resultados de los comandos mencionados en los comentarios son los siguientes
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes indicarnos que te devuelven los siguientes comandos?
`apt-cache show mysql-common | grep Version`
`apt-cache show libmysqlclient18 | grep Version`
`apt-cache show mariadb-common | grep Version`
`apt-cache show libmariadbclient18 | grep Version`

Comment: los resultados son los siguintes a los comandos anteriores

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este comando

```
apt update
apt install -y mariadb-server mariadb-client
```

Lo he realizado desde debian 8 y no me falla.

Si te aparecen otros procesos sobre el paquete a instalar probablemente tengas instalado ya otra versión. Tal vez te convenga buscar los paquetes mencionados en los comentarios y tratar de actualizarlos/borrarlos/instalarlos.